# Angular2 : Read JSON file using http get

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to read a json file using http get but I am getting below error.

`Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

please help me on what is wrong.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { peopleService } from './PeopleService';


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
//providers: [peopleService]
})

export class AppComponent {
//jsonFile: string = './EmployeeHeader.json';
empdata: Observable<Array<any>>[];

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('../assets/EmployeeHeader.json')
        .map(Response => Response.json())
        .subscribe(empdata => this.empdata = empdata, error => console.log(error));
    //this.empdata = service.getPeople();
    //console.log('Data is: ' + this.empdata);
}
}
```

Adding the HTMl part below for reference,

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let t of empdata">
<td>{{t.wwid}}</td>
<td>{{t.name}}</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>{{t.idsid}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: folder structure]

JSON format of the code for your reference and I am not sure if any issue with this

```
   {
"Employee":
[
  {
    "name": "Karthik Shekhar",
    "wwid": "11597210",
    "idsid": "kshekh1x",
    "costCenterCode": "80790",
    "mgrWWID": "10693268",
    "orgUnit": "67926"
  },
  {
    "name": "Aneesur Rahman",
    "wwid": "11744439",
    "idsid": "aneesurx",
    "costCenterCode": "32406",
    "mgrWWID": "10693268",
    "orgUnit": "67926"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ashutosh Pandey",
    "wwid": "11691980",
    "idsid": "ashuto3x",
    "costCenterCode": "32406",
    "mgrWWID": "10693268",
    "orgUnit": "67926"
  },
]
}
```

Comment: How do you implement *ngfor in your html part?

Comment: This is because `ngFor` binds to iterables like arrays and not an object. One  of the workaround can be: `this.empdata = [empdata]`. However there can be alot better solution than this. Also if you can share you response that you are getting from the API and your html `ngFor` structure?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure. I think your http get request executed with 404 and *ngFor didn't receives expected array so it throws error

Comment: mmm .. ican you post your EmployeeHeader.json ..and can you try to  set empdata: Array<any>=[]

Comment: shared the HTML part

Comment: @ARUN No. If its a 404, angular by default will throw an error, and there will not even be any data in the response. OP clearly gets the data form the response, its just not being able to iterated properly

Comment: @Aneez can you show a sample of your `json` file?

Comment: Please share your employeeHeader.json

Comment: shared the json

Answer (score 2):

Your `empdata` was an object, not an array. You need to access the `Employee` property in your object:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('../assets/EmployeeHeader.json')
        .map(Response => Response.json())
        .subscribe(empdata => {
            //access Employee property
            this.empdata = empdata.Employee
        }, error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this json data bind to autocomplete input field based on drop down. For example, if I choose _name_ in the drop down, it should display all Employee.name values. _wwid_ should show all Employee.wwid value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

change your service like below

```
  this.http.get('../assets/EmployeeHeader.json')
            .map(Response => Response.json())
            .subscribe(empdata => {this.empdata = empdata.Employee}
    , error => console.log(error));
```

or
change the *ngFor to

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let t of empdata.Employee">
<td>{{t.wwid}}</td>
<td>{{t.name}}</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>{{t.idsid}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: In html, reference to Employee is not needed as you have already assigned that in subscribe call.

Comment: if it is not assigned then it is needed that's why i have mentioned or in my answer

Comment: Oh ok. I thought html was added in continuation.